# show and start hidden video after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, hidden

I need an easy way to cover a youtube Video with an image and when I click on it, the video should show up and start.

What is the easiest way to get this done?

I tried to make a css change on click, but it doesnt work out. It works with a css :hover effect but not with jquery.?

```
<div id='videowrapper'>                                   
  <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FLgkfNNBVj4?wmode=transparent&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&hd=1&autohide=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>                            
</div>

#videowrapper{
    width:560px;
    height:315px;
    background:url("//");
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:100px -40px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid white;

  }

  #video{

    opacity:0;

  }

  <script>
  $('#video').click(function(){
  $('#video').css('opacity','0');
  $('this').css('opacity','1');
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to hide the element and then show it once something has been clicked.

```
<div id="videowrapper">
  <div id="clickArea"></div>
  <iframe style="display:none" id="video" //blah ></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('#clickArea').on('click', function () {
    $('#video').show();
    $('#clickArea').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

You would need to add styling to the click area, this is just example code of what you could do.

Comment: Hey thanks, but the video doesn't start after I clicked on #clickarea. What do I need to add to start the video?  How about setting css of the #video to visibility:hidden and changing the css with jquery to visbility: visible? But I dont know the jquery code for that.